# SQL Server nvarchar comparison with empty space

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

We've got interesting issue from production today :) Everything is fine now but I still don't understand one thing. Let me show you the query.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#results', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #results;

CREATE TABLE #results(
    [id] smallint,
    [name] nvarchar(128)
)
insert into #results values (1, 'JOHN NOWAK      '), (2, 'frog'), (3, 'wine')

declare @nazwa_p nvarchar(128) = 'JOHN NOWAK';

SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] = @nazwa_p
SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] like @nazwa_p
```

First query result is

```
1   JOHN NOWAK
```

The second query gives me nothing. Why is that? Does the  `=` operator run `RTRIM()` method?

Thank's for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing spaces are ignored in equality comparisons. In your like clause, you are missing `%`. I added a new variable to show how this can be done.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#results', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #results;

CREATE TABLE #results(
    [id] smallint,
    [name] nvarchar(128)
)
insert into #results values (1, 'JOHN NOWAK      '), (2, 'frog'), (3, 'wine')

declare @nazwa_p nvarchar(128) = 'JOHN NOWAK';

declare @nazwa_p2 nvarchar(128) = '%JOHN NOWAK%';

SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] = @nazwa_p
SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] like @nazwa_p2
SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] like '%' +  @nazwa_p + '%'
```

Comment: Thank for answer. We already add wildcard matching %. But we don't know that trailing spaces are ignored in equality comparisons. I cannot find this in documentation :)

Comment: [It's ANSI standards](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces). You can set your instance to **not** ignore the spaces if you'd like

Answer (score 1):

When you use the equal (=) operator, SQL server pads the two values to be of equal length. This is also happening with other operators such as HAVING or WHERE. See the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification.

The like operator does not do that padding. This is the only difference between using equal operator and the LIKE operator without a wildcard. To obtain the same result you would need:

```
     SELECT * FROM #results WHERE [name] like CONCAT('[ ]',@nazwa_p,'[ ]')
```

In this case, LIKE would match any number of spaces before or after the given text. (note that in the example above there is a space in between the square brackets.